Page List Block doesn't show all pages in edit
When adding a Page List Block it cuts of the last of my pages in the page-list in edit.
When viewing the page in view-mode, it shows all of them.
That wouldn't be so bad - but the page I want to use as a parent I also can't find in the dropdown for choosing a parent - here also only the pages are listed that are shown in edit.
The pages are published and can be viewed.
In edit:

In view-mode:


I had the same problem with WordPress 6.6.2, even with the Gutenberg 19.4.0 plugin installed.
I have found the following workaround: Temporarily unpublish pages you don't want to select as the parent page of your page list (set them to draft). Since the dropdown only shows published pages, this will bring up the page you are looking for.
Interestingly, this page will remain in the dropdown menu even if you republish the other pages.
